# Jackson json to map and camelcase key name

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to convert json via jackson library to a map containing camelCase key...say...

**from**

```
{
    "SomeKey": "SomeValue",
    "AnotherKey": "another value",
    "InnerJson" : {"TheKey" : "TheValue"}
}
```

**to this...**

```
{
    "someKey": "SomeValue",
    "anotherKey": "another value",
    "innerJson" : {"theKey" : "TheValue"}
}
```

My Code...

```
public Map<String, Object> jsonToMap(String jsonString) throws IOException
{
    ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
    return mapper.readValue(jsonString,new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});
}
```

But this doesn't work...even other propertyNamingStrategy does not work on json...such as...

```
{
    "someKey": "SomeValue"
}

mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new PropertyNamingStrategy.PascalCaseStrategy())
```

to

```
{
    "SomeKey": "SomeValue"
}
```

**How to get the camelCase Map key name via jackson... or should I manually loop map and convert key or there are some other way???**

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This looks along the lines of what you are trying to achieve: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/62

Answer (score 9):

As you are working with maps/dictionaries instead of binding the JSON data to POJOs (explicit Java classes that match the JSON data), the property naming strategy does not apply:

> Class PropertyNamingStrategy ... defines how names of JSON properties
>   ("external names") are derived from names of POJO methods and fields
>   ("internal names")

Therefore, you have to first parse the data using Jackson and then iterate over the result and convert the keys.

Change your code like this:

```
public Map<String, Object> jsonToMap(String jsonString) throws IOException
{
    ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
    Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(jsonString,new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});
    return convertMap(map);
}
```

And add these methods:

```
public String mapKey(String key) {
    return Character.toLowerCase(key.charAt(0)) + key.substring(1);
}

public Map<String, Object> convertMap(Map<String, Object> map) {
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Object value = entry.getValue();
        result.put(mapKey(key), convertValue(value));
    }
    return result;
}

public convertList(Lst<Object> list) {
    List<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for (Object obj : list) {
        result.add(convertValue(obj));
    }
    return result;
}

public Object covertValue(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Map<String, Object>) {
        return convertMap((Map<String, Object>) obj);
    } else if (obj instanceof List<Object>) {
        return convertList((List<Object>) obj);
    } else {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time and note that was a problem of property naming strategy not applying to non POJO objects.  I'm working on in a legacy project so changing maps by POJO's wasn't an option. However the proposed methods were really helpful and I've managed to get the right mapping by doing a few adjustments.

Comment: This saved my life. I thought I was doing something wrong!
BTW Guava `CaseFormat` is very useful for String conversion instead of rewriting mapKey.
https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained#caseformat

Answer (score 8):

You always can iterate over the keys of the map and update  them. However, if you are only interested in producing a JSON with camel case keys, you could consider the approach described below.

You could have a custom key serializer. It will be used when serializing a `Map` instance to JSON:

```java
public class CamelCaseKeySerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
                throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        String key = Character.toLowerCase(value.charAt(0)) + value.substring(1);
        gen.writeFieldName(key);
    }
}
```

Then do as following:

```java
String json = "{\"SomeKey\":\"SomeValue\",\"AnotherKey\":\"another value\",\"InnerJson\":"
            + "{\"TheKey\":\"TheValue\"}}";

SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
simpleModule.addKeySerializer(String.class, new CamelCaseKeySerializer());

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(simpleModule);

Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(json, 
                                          new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});

String camelCaseJson = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(map);
```

The output will be:

```json
{
  "someKey" : "SomeValue",
  "anotherKey" : "another value",
  "innerJson" : {
    "theKey" : "TheValue"
  }
}
```

With this approach, the keys of the `Map` won't be in camel case. But it will give you the desired output.

Comment: It is the fastest and most complete solution. I was able to build my custom serializer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following will transform json with keys on any "case format" to using camelCased keys:

```
/**
 * Convert all property keys of the specified JSON to camelCase
 */
public static String toJsonWithCamelCasedKeys(String json) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule()
      .addKeySerializer(String.class, new JsonSerializer<>() {
          @Override
          public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
              String key = CaseUtil.toCamelCase(value);
              gen.writeFieldName(key);
          }
      })
    );

    try {
        Map<String, Object> jsonMap = objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<>() {});
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(jsonMap);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new JsonException("Error transforming JSON", e);
    }
}
```

...and a CaseUtil implementation could be something like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CaseUtil {

    public static String toCamelCase(String s) {
        if (s == null) {
            return null;
        }
        else if (s.isBlank()) {
            return "";
        }

        return decapitaliseFirstLetter(
          String.join("", Arrays.stream(s.split("[-_\\s]"))
          .map(CaseUtil::capitaliseFirstLetter)
          .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        );
    }

    private static String capitaliseFirstLetter(String s) {
        return (s.length() > 0)
          ? s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1)
          : s;
    }

    private static String decapitaliseFirstLetter(String s) {
        return (s.length() > 0)
          ? s.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase() + s.substring(1)
          : s;
    }

}
```

A unit test:

```
    @Test
    void jsonWithMiscCasedPropKeys_shouldConvertKeyToCamelCase() throws Exception {
        String inputJson =
            "{\"kebab-prop\": \"kebab\"," +
            "\"snake_prop\": \"snake\"," +
            "\"PascalProp\": \"pascal\"," +
            "\"camelCasedProp\": \"camel\"}";
        String expectedJson =
          "{\"kebabProp\": \"kebab\"," +
            "\"snakeProp\": \"snake\"," +
            "\"pascalProp\": \"pascal\"," +
            "\"camelCasedProp\": \"camel\"}";
        String actualJson = Json.toJsonWithCamelCasedKeys(inputJson);

        JSONAssert.assertEquals(expectedJson, actualJson, JSONCompareMode.LENIENT);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ref @codo's answer, I modified another version

```
 public static Map<String, Object> snakeToCamelMap(Map<String, Object> map) {
    if (MapUtils.isEmpty(map)) {
      return map;
    }
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
      String key = entry.getKey();
      Object value = entry.getValue();
      result.put(snakeToCamelString(key), snakeToCamel(value));
    }
    return result;
  }

  public static List<Object> snakeToCamelList(List<Object> list) {
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list)) {
      return list;
    }
    List<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object o : list) {
      result.add(snakeToCamel(o));
    }
    return result;
  }

  public static Object snakeToCamel(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Map) {
      return snakeToCamelMap((Map<String, Object>) obj);
    } else if (obj instanceof List) {
      return snakeToCamelList((List) obj);
    } else {
      return obj;
    }
  }

  private static String snakeToCamelString(String key) {
    if (key.contains("_")) {
      return CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL, key);
    }
    return key;
  }
```