# Jackson map to json with changing case

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to convert map to json but with changing case using jackson. For example, I have this map:

```
 "test_first" -> 1,
 "test_second" -> 2,
```

I want to convert it to json but with changing from underscore case to lowerCamelCase. How do I do that? Using this didn't help:

```
// Map<String, String> fields;

var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.LOWER_CAMEL_CASE); 
// setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE) didn't help too
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(fields);
```

Comment: Reading the [API](https://mirrors.aliyun.com/android.googlesource.com/external/jackson-databind/docs/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html), from what I understand, you have to do it the other way aroung using `SnakeCaseStrategy`:  

_PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy
A PropertyNamingStrategy that translates typical camel case Java property names to lower case JSON element names, separated by underscores._

But I'm not sure if it works with a simple map key since the key is not a property of a Java object.

Comment: @TheFrozenOnem, I don't understand, you're saying that it will change the CamelCase to underscore case, but I need to do vice versa: from underscore case map to json string containing camelCase

Comment: Ok, got it. If your example above in JSON style is a Java object, you should post it as a Java object like `Map<> someMap = new HashMap();`
You should also post your output, or the problem, you're facing. 
Anyway, I think, someone else already explained it:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39413177/7132739

Comment: @TheFrozenOne, Try to read the question next time, there's no one accepted style on how to display a value of a map, so I wrote it like this, it doesn't matter because I literally wrote before "I have this map:". And the question you linked is doing vice versa: from json to map, and is not helpful because it's hardcoded to only one use case: from UpperCamelCase to lowerCamelCase

Comment: It exactly describes the solution to your problem. And it might help others to help you if you provide a clear and complete example.

Comment: @TheFrozenOne, no, it's not, I already explained why, and about "clear example":  in the question you linked the author describes a map literally as I did in the first version, I guess it was a clear example then, so what's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`StringKeySerializer`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/StdKeySerializers.StringKeySerializer.html) in Jackson which may implement the functionality to change presentation of the keys in some map (e.g. using Guava [`CaseFormat`](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CaseFormat.html)):

```java
// custom key serializer
class SnakeToCamelMapKeySerialiser extends StdKeySerializers.StringKeySerializer {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator g, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException {
        g.writeFieldName(CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL, (String) value));
    }
}

// map with the custom serializer
@JsonSerialize(keyUsing = SnakeToCamelMapKeySerialiser.class)
class MyMap<K extends String, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {
}
```

Then the map is serialized with the required format:

```java
Map<String, Integer> map = new MyMap<>();
map.put("first_key", 1);
map.put("second_key", 2);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();


String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(map);

System.out.println(json);
// -> {"firstKey":1,"secondKey":2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `@JsonProperty` annotation. Over your property variable or over its getter do this:

```
@JsonProperty("testFirst")
String test_first;

@JsonProperty("testSecond")
String test_second;
```

Apparently you can also use `@JsonGetter` and `@JsonSetter` annotations as an alternative. Read about it in [Jackson Annotation Examples](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations) areticle

Comment: This is not the case because I'm converting a map, not an object

Comment: OK, not sure how to do it in the map than