# Jackson deserialization : Unrecognized field

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, fasterxml

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON but I still get the same ***UnrecognizedPropertyException*** even though the Object has all the properties needed for the process of deserialization, at least I think!

The property not recognized is "deleteFile" .

Here the JSON:

```
{
    "host" : "xxx.xxx.xxxx",
    "port" : 22,
    "credential" : "yyyyy",,
    "path" : "/xx/yy/zz/",
    "name" : "readme.txt",
    "type": "TXT",
    "direction" : "TO_KUBE",
    "deleteFile": true
}
```

Here the POJO classes:

```
public class FileTransferStructureExecution<F extends FileStructure> extends FileTransferStructure<F> {


    private Integer fixedLength;
    private Boolean flagJes = false;

    public FileTransferStructureExecution() {}
    
    public FileTransferStructureExecution(F fileStructure) {
        super(fileStructure);
    }
    
    public FileTransferStructureExecution(TransferDirection direction, String path, String name, FileType type) {
        super(direction, path, name, type);
    }
    
    public FileTransferStructureExecution(TransferDirection direction, String path, String name, FileType type, String credential) {
        super(direction, path, name, type, credential);
    }
    // getters and setters
}

public class FileTransferStructure<F extends FileStructure> {

    private TransferDirection direction;
    private String path;
    private String name;
    private String inputName;
    private FileType type;
    private String host;
    private String port;
    private String credential;
    private Boolean deleteSource = false;
    private Boolean deleteFile = false;
    private F fileStructure;
    
    public FileTransferStructure() {}
    
    public FileTransferStructure(F fileStructure) {
        this.path = fileStructure.getPath();
        this.name = fileStructure.getName();
        this.type = fileStructure.getType();
        this.fileStructure = fileStructure;
    }
    
    public FileTransferStructure(TransferDirection direction, String path, String name, FileType type) {
        this.direction = direction;
        this.path = path;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }
    
    public FileTransferStructure(TransferDirection direction, String path, String name, FileType type, String credential) {
        this.direction = direction;
        this.path = path;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.credential = credential;
    }
    // getters and setters

 }
 
 public enum FileType {
     CSV, XLS, XLSX, TXT, KSQL;
 }

 public enum TransferDirection {
    TO_KUBE, FROM_KUBE;
 }
```

*FileStructure* class :

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class FileStructure {

    private FileType type;
    private String path;
    private String name;
    private Boolean compress = false;
    
    public FileStructure() {}
    
    public FileStructure(FileType type, String path, String name) {
        this.type = type;
        this.path = path;
        this.name = name;
    }
    // getters and setters
}
```

The *ObjectMapper* readValue() call , which is the source of the exception :

```
protected <C> C parseJson(String content, Class<C> clazz) throws MB3BfException {
        try {
            ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            return jsonMapper.readValue(content, clazz);
        }catch(IOException e) {
            throw new MB3BfException("Cannot decode action content", e);
        }
    }
```

Here the detailed exception :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "deleteFile" (class eu.unicredit.mb3.kube.business.executor.pojo.FileTransferStructureExecution), not marked as ignorable (12 known properties: "port", "path", "deleteSource", "credential", "host", "type", "name", "flagJes", "direction", "inputName", "fileStructure", "fixedLength"])
 at [Source: {
    "host" : "xxx.xxx.xxxx",
    "port" : 22,
    "credential" : "yyyyy",
    "path" : "/xx/yy/zz/",
    "name" : "readme.txt",
    "type": "TXT",
    "direction" : "TO_KUBE",
    "deleteFile": true
}; line: 9, column: 23] (through reference chain: eu.unicredit.mb3.kube.business.executor.pojo.FileTransferStructureExecution["deleteFile"])
```

I want to have the property "`deleteFile`" recognized for deserialization.
What could be the problem ? thank you !

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39413177/3636601) should help you

Comment: The message error seems referring to the `FileTransferStructureExecution` class, not to the `FileTransferStructure`class.

Comment: `TransferDirection` and `FileType` are still missing.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko what do you mean ?

Comment: I mean that I can't try to parse the sample data without these two classes.

Comment: Not sure if it can help but I noticed `deleteSource` property is visible, there is some difference between `deleteSource` setter and `deleteFile` setter?

Comment: Hi @dariosicily , no differences between deleteSource and deleteFile