# Java: how to deserialise and transform name strategy for complex Map

Tags: java, dictionary, jackson, deserialization, fasterxml

I have a map with dynamic structure *Map<String, Object>*, where value - Object can be number, string or another *Map<String, Object>*

I need to transform all keys name strategy from *snake_case* to *camelCase*

**Example**

**Input**

```
{
    "some_key_level1": "v1" ,
    "some_key2_level1": "v2",
    "some_map": {
        "some_key_level2": "v1",
        "some_key2_level2": "v2",
        "other_map": {...}
    },
    "some_key3_level1": "v3",
}
```

**Expected result**

```
{
    "someKeyLevel1": "v1" ,
    "someKey2Level1": "v2",
    "someMap": {
        "someKeyLevel2": "v1",
        "someKey2Level2": "v2",
        "otherMap": {...}
    },
    "someKey3Level1": "v3",
}
```

This code can help with this, but only in the first nesting level.

```
SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
simpleModule.addKeyDeserializer(String.class, new CamelCaseKeyDeserializer());
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(simpleModule);

 private static class CamelCaseKeyDeserializer extends KeyDeserializer {
        @Override
        public Object deserializeKey(String key, DeserializationContext ctxt) {
            if (key != null) {
                return CaseFormat.LOWER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.LOWER_CAMEL, key);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

How to transform *all* keys for dynamic Map

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39413177/1271785) help?

Comment: @pfurbacher Thanks. But unfortunately it doesn't not help. First solution with method convertMap(map) can deserialize keys only on first or second level, but not deeper. Second approach make transformation while Serialize process, and of course it is possible to do  deserialisation -> serialisation  -> deserialisation but it's not ok for perfomance